# Animation Performance with a large number of components

Tags: angular, performance, components

Lets start with the good news first: my code works.
Now for the bad news : the performance is really a problem.

In a nutshell, I have an application with:

1. One Component that contain a toggle button
2. 400 individual components.

When someone clicks on the toggle button, I change the color of each one of my 400 components using the animate module.

In term of architecture I have :

- An observable attached to the button
- Each 400 components subscribing to the observable.
- The 400 components are not child of my button component, so I use a shared Service to exchange information.

With this in place, I am experiencing a 2 seconds lag between the click and the color change.

From what I can see in the logs, the bulk of this time appears to be spent on each one of my component listening to the click event. The animation itself happens almost instantly once **ALL** the 400 components are done receiving the click event.

So before I start tearing my code apart to implement it differently : Am I doing something off?  Or am I just reaching the limits of the framework for my this architecture choice ?

Comment: I wonder if your doing something odd to trigger change detection for each component.

Comment: Set your topmost component to the OnPush change detection strategy